# How do you provide real time push notifications in iOS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

We have an XMPP chat client that is APNS enabled. Everytime, the other user has the app inactive, we trigger a push on the server to alert the other user that he has unread messages in the app. Our current implementation is we have a queue that passes it to a cron job that runs every minute that constructs the payload and forwards it to the Apple Servers. Now the problem is, this is taking too long, since the app is a chat client, the user expects that they will receive the push notification immediately (a few seconds of delay is acceptable of course, because I understand that even apple could take a while in sending the push notifications, but in my experience, it takes seconds for the client to receive it).

Now I know Apple has limitations when it comes to requests unlike C2DM (now known as GCM), so that is why we are putting it on a queue, and passing it to a cron job. Other apps are doing it, and I don't really know how exactly they are doing it really close to real time.

Here are some of my questions:

- Do we need to change our implementation? (the queue and the cron job).
- Is having multiple Providers a solution to the problem? If yes, what are the requirements for this?
- Are there any paid services that is already doing this? Can anyone name some?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Urban Airship. http://urbanairship.com.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding paid services please check http://pushwoosh.com, they have API integration as one of the options. This might help.